# Can I use "overstrike" to say "make a font a bold font"?

Tags: word-usage

After looking up a dictionary, I found *overstriking* as noun.

As *striking* also has a meaning when talking of HTML markup (referring to text rendered with the `<strike>` tag), can I use *overstrike* to say "make a font a bold font"?

Answer (score 5):

In typography, overstriking is printing more than once in the same place.  That can mean striking twice with the same character, or with two different characters.  It doesn't *usually* mean bold, and if you said "overstrike", I doubt people would know that bold was what you meant.

You can use overstriking to create, for example:

1. **Strikethrough characters**.  By typing a `-` over an `e`, you can create a crossed-out `e`.
2. **Bold characters**.  By typing the same character twice, but slightly offset horizontally, you can create the impression of a bold character.

However, neither of these look very good, and they might be called "fake strikethrough" and "fake bold".  They were useful once, and still are in limited circumstances, but most people don't use overstrike for either of these things anymore.  Most people use actual *bold fonts* which have special bold characters, and strikethrough is usually rendered as a single line, not a series of dashes.

Still, it's possible to create bold in this way, so you're not entirely wrong.  But if you want to say bold, **say bold**.  If you want to say strikethrough, say **strikethrough**.  And only talk about overstriking when you want to discuss **printing twice in the same place**.

(Or, as J.R. points out, if you want to talk about a coin which has been struck twice.)

Comment: Ah, the good old dot-matrix printer days...

Answer (score 2):

No, don't use *overstrike* to describe bold print.

When coins are minted, the design of the coin is "struck" onto the blank coin. If a coin moves slightly as it's being struck, it can end up being "double struck," as happened to this coin:

[image]

Overstriking, then, would imply more of a blurred look to the font, rather than a cleanly bolded font.

Comment: +1 Nifty. You might add that the usual term is "strike through" (verb) or "strikethrough" (noun).

Comment: Overstrike *is* used for bold, e.g. in xterm.  @StoneyB Note that *overstrike* is distinct from *strikethrough*.

Comment: @snailboat Yes, I expressed myself confusingly. I meant that *strikethrough* is the usual term for the effect called for by OP's html example `<strike>strike</strike>`.

Comment: @snailboat And if I understand the xterm tutorials I find online, *overstrike* is not equivalent to "bold": it is a means of achieving a bold-like effect if a bold font is not specified.

Comment: @snailboat And now I see that you have said all that in your Answer!

Comment: J.R., so the "blank coin" is the unprinted coin, but is this an idiomatic usage?

Comment: @Carlo_R. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planchet